# How do I get diffs of all the files in a pending Perforce changelist?

Tags: shell, terminal, perforce, csh

I want to get diffs on files in a specific pending changelist.  I wish I could do this:

```
p4 diff -c 999
```

Can someone help me string together some csh magic to make this happen?

Maybe take the output of `p4 opened -c 999` and piping it to `p4 diff`?

Comment: Shelve the changes in the pending changelist, then run

`p4 describe -S -du 999`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way is in p4v or p4win, but that's not what you were asking about.

Try this:

```
p4 opened -c 999 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "#" } // { print "p4 diff " $1 }' | csh
```

You, of course, need to make sure that the sub shell has p4 in its path, and $P4CLIENT, etc... are all set up.

Comment: great that works!  one question though, how can I replace the 999 with a variable to use in an alias.  This is as far as I got but my understanding of alias parameters and escaping rules is limited.

alias p4diffchange 'p4 opened -c $1 | `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "#" } // { print "p4 diff " $2 }'` | csh';

Comment: Don't use an alias, put it in a shell script and use the script's positional parameters.

Comment: What a pain!  Why doesn't Perforce support displaying the diffs of a pending changelist with `p4 describe`?

Comment: Note that this won't work for added or deleted files.

Answer (score 27):

Shelve the changes in the pending changelist, then run

```
p4 describe -S -du 999
```

Comment: Hadn't heard of shelving before. Tried this and it worked a treat.

Comment: This works, but it ought to be possible without having to shelve anything. Perforce need to do usability testing.

Comment: Also, there's no way to apply the resulting patch file. It's incompatible with the unix patch command "Only garbage was found in the patch input", and there isn't any special `p4 patch` command as you might expect.

Comment: "Perforce need to do usability testing." - Waiting for it to die off completely is more of a hopeful prospect at this point.

Answer (score 19):

## Solution

```
p4 opened -c 999 | sed -e 's/#.*//' | p4 -x - diff
```

## Explanation

`p4 -x` gives you [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) like ability without having to use `xargs`. From `p4 help utils`:

> The -x flag instructs p4 to read arguments, one per line, from the
>     specified file.  If you specify '-', standard input is read.

So you can almost just "take the output of p4 opened -c 999 and pipe it to p4 diff" as suggested in the question. The one tricky part is that the output of `p4 opened` contains revision numbers and explanatory text after the name of each open file e.g.

```
//depot/example#123 - edit change 999 (text) by day@office
//depot/new-example#1 - add change 999 (text) by day@office
```

But we can run this through a simple `sed -e 's/#.*//'` to strip off everything from the `#` onwards to leave just the paths:

```
//depot/example
//depot/new-example
```

which can then be consumed from standard input and fed to `p4 diff` thanks to `p4 -x -`.

If you have `#` in the names of any files then you'll need to get more clever with the `sed` command. And see a psychiatrist.

Comment: jwd: That's true, but I don't think any of the other solutions work for added files either... Trouble is that `p4 diff newfile` itself will just say `//depot/newfile - file(s) not opened for edit.` Not very helpful.

Comment: This works nicely with Kaleidoscope, my preferred $P4DIFF tool.

Answer (score 10):

p4 describe 999  | grep '#' | cut -d"#" -f1|cut -d" " -f2 | xargs p4 diff

Comment: This does not work for a pending changelist, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It does work for me for a pending changelist in a very smooth fashion. I even created an alias for that long line of pipes. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this does not work for added or deleted files.

Answer (score 6):

You can use shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

list=`p4 opened -c $1 | cut -d# -f1`

for file in $list ;
do
  p4 diff -dwbu $file
done
```

call it with changelist number and you'll get patch in stdout.

Comment: Is it possible to create something similar in windows batch file? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar approach as Mark, but I used Perl instead of Awk, and a shell function (in zsh):

```
p4dc() { p4 opened -c $* | perl -ne 's/#.*//; system("p4", "diff", $_)' }
```

Note that you can provide a file path too, in addition to just the changelist name/number:

```
p4dc default | less
p4dc default ... | less
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one-liner that works from the Windows cmd shell, try this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=#" %F in (`p4 opened -c 999`) do @p4 diff %F
```

To do this in a batch file you need to use `%%F` instead of just `%F`.

Note that some of the solution above will work under Windows if you have installed a unix-like utilities package such as [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [unixutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), but this one-liner has no external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers your question but, if tile is read as diffing a directory on a change list it can be answered with the following:

```
p4 filelog ... | awk '
BEGIN {FS="[ /]";tc=999}
/^\/\// {fn=$NF;o=1;if (system("test -w " fn)) h=0; else h=""}
/^\.\.\.\ \#/ {if (h==0) h=$2;
  if ($4<=tc && o==1) {print "p4 diff -db -dw " fn h " " fn $2 " ;#"  $4;o=0}}' \
| sh
```

This will diff all the files in the directory against the changelist 999 it uses the "have" version if it has be checked out otherwise it uses the latest version.

this was tested with GNU Awk 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

For Unshelved Changes( Changes still not in depot)

```
p4 opened -c 999 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "#" } // { print "p4 diff " $1 }' | bash
```

For Shelved Changes( Changes that in depot ( p4 shelve -c 999)

```
p4 describe -S -du3 -O 999
```